# How to profile an app running inside KVM guest

Tags: profiling, virtualization, kvm, perf

Is there any way to profile an application running inside KVM guest using a tool like perf_events?

I've tried to do that using

```
perf kvm --guestkallsyms=.. --guestmodules=.. --guest record -a
```

but information in report is pretty useless:

```
# ========
#
# Samples: 627  of event 'cache-misses'
# Event count (approx.): 295421
#
# Overhead  Command     Shared Object                  Symbol
# ........  .......  ................  ......................
#
    73.18%   :15661  [x_tables]        [g] 0xffffffff8176bc80
    26.82%   :15661  [unknown]         [u] 0x00000000004004fe


#
# (For a higher level overview, try: perf report --sort comm,dso)
#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The perf tool runs in the host and does not have any way to get information about the applications in the guest. I think the attribution of samples to guest-kernelspace or guest-userspace is based on the cpu-mode at the time the sample was taken (not on higher-level information about what the guest is doing).

You can get some profiling information by running perf directly in the guest. Use `perf list` to see the options (they are probably all in the 'software' category).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably can. The host can see the guest. You can use raw hardware events to do so (just check the event number to be available on your system). 
For me this works as an example:

```
sudo perf kvm stat -I 1000 -e r1a8 -a
```

(make sure you are monitoring the guest by turning off the KVM machine after a while and see the zeros ..)

Answer (score -1):

yes, 
what about

```
sudo perf kvm stat record  -p appPID
```

it should work based on the help of perf kvm but it does not! it works fine in system wide mode with -a

Comment: It will not work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997809 - host kernel have no process tables of guest kernel. (Kvm guest may also be non-linux and non-unix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine "*A wide variety of guest operating systems work with KVM, including many flavours and versions of Linux, BSD, Solaris, Windows, Haiku, ReactOS, Plan 9, ... *")