# How can a specific application be monitored by perf inside the kvm?

Tags: kvm, perf

I have an application which I want to monitor it via perf stat when running inside a kvm VM. 
After Googling I have found that perf kvm stat can do this. However there is an error by running the command:

```
sudo perf kvm stat record  -p appPID
```

which results in help representation ...

```
usage: perf kvm stat record [<options>]

-p, --pid <pid>       record events on existing process id
-t, --tid <tid>       record events on existing thread id
-r, --realtime <n>    collect data with this RT SCHED_FIFO priority
    --no-buffering    collect data without buffering
-a, --all-cpus        system-wide collection from all CPUs
-C, --cpu <cpu>       list of cpus to monitor
-c, --count <n>       event period to sample
-o, --output <file>   output file name
-i, --no-inherit      child tasks do not inherit counters
-m, --mmap-pages <pages[,pages]>
                      number of mmap data pages and AUX area tracing mmap pages
-v, --verbose         be more verbose (show counter open errors, etc)
-q, --quiet           don't print any message
```

Does any one know what is the problem?

Comment: You have the syntax wrong. I have no idea where you found the `kvm` part, but general syntax is `perf stat record  -p appPID`

Comment: !my app is in a guest , your comment will record the app which is in host.

Answer (score 4):

Use kvm with vPMU (virtualization of PMU counters)  - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Tuning_and_Optimization_Guide/sect-Virtualization_Tuning_Optimization_Guide-Monitoring_Tools-vPMU.html "2.2. VIRTUAL PERFORMANCE MONITORING UNIT (VPMU)"). Then run `perf record -p $pid` and `perf stat -p $pid` inside the guest.

Host system has no knowledge (tables) of guest processes (they are managed by guest kernel, which can be non Linux, or different version of linux with incompatible table format), so host kernel can't profile some specific guest process. It only can profile whole guest (and there is `perf kvm` command - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Tuning_and_Optimization_Guide/chap-Virtualization_Tuning_Optimization_Guide-Monitoring_Tools.html#sect-Virtualization_Tuning_Optimization_Guide-Monitoring_Tools-perf_kvm)

Comment: Hey, this is a good answer, I am searching whether there is a way to monitor guest process's kvm events(eg. kvm:kvm_exit) on host, Sadly there is no way.